# Get the name of the first category

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a single page that lists the content of each category. I have managed to create the list. I now need to get the name of the category. I have the following code:

```
<ul>
    <li> CATEGORY NAME HERE </li>

    <?php query_posts('cat=0'); ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

How to call the name of the first category (0)?

**Current edit**: Why won't multiple works?

```
<div class="first-col">
    <ul>
        <?php query_posts('cat=0'); ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <li> <?php $category = get_the_category(); 
        echo $category[0]->cat_name;
        ?> </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="first-col">
    <ul>
        <li> <?php $category = get_the_category(); 
        echo $category[0]->cat_name;?> </li>

        <?php query_posts('cat=3'); ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 24):

You have to get the array of categories and echo the first one from the array.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->cat_name;
?>
```

Comment: I've copied and pasted that code directly within the first `li` element, but it's not showing anything.

Comment: What happens when you print the categories?
print_r(get_the_category());

Comment: It prints that within the `li` instead of any category title!

Comment: And what happens when you use print_r(get_the_category(0)); ?

Comment: Just put it inside the loop, and the first solution works perfectly!

Comment: Hmmm, with multiple loops on one page it seems to go funny. It works if it's within the loop on the first call, but has to be outside of the loop on the second call. — edited first post with the problem

Comment: What happens when you put <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> at the end of the query posts. So after each endwhile.

Answer (score 4):

According to wordpress developers codex:

```
    $categories = get_the_category();
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a>';
}
```

This will give you the first category and also link it to that category's page.

Answer (score -1):

there is also a shortcodes plug in that will help create lists based on categories, terms, etc. http://wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/